# Copy the all <item> attribute from input XML file to output xml file through xquery

Tags: xml, xpath, xquery, marklogic

**First xml file is prices information:**

```
<prices>
    <priceList effDate="2006-11-15">
        <prod num="557">
            <price currency="USD">29.99</price>
            <discount type="CLR">10.00</discount>
        </prod>
        <prod num="563">
            <price currency="USD">69.99</price>
        </prod>
        <prod num="443">
            <price currency="USD">39.99</price>
            <discount type="CLR">3.99</discount>
        </prod>
    </priceList>
</prices>
```

**second XML file is order information**

```
<order num="00299432" date="2006-09-15" cust="0221A">
    <item dept="WMN" num="557" quantity="1" color="navy">
        <prod num="557">
            <price currency="USD">29.99</price>
            <discount type="CLR">10.00</discount>
        </prod>
    </item>
    <item dept="ACC" num="563" quantity="1"/>
    <item dept="ACC" num="443" quantity="2"/>
    <item dept="MEN" num="784" quantity="1" color="white"/>
    <item dept="MEN" num="784" quantity="1" color="gray"/>
    <item dept="WMN" num="557" quantity="1" color="black"/>
</order>
```

**My expected output is below like that, means all `<prod>` element come under the `<item>` with all `<item>` attributes information**

```
<item dept="WMN" num="557" quantity="1" color="navy">
<prod num="557">
<price currency="USD">29.99</price>
<discount type="CLR">10.00</discount>
</prod>
</item>
```

**MY CODE is below like that:**

```
let $prices := fn:doc('/training/prices.xml')/prices
let $order := fn:doc('/training/order.xml')/order
where $prices/priceList/prod[@num=$order/item/@num]
for $kk in $prices/priceList/prod[@num=$order/item/@num]
return 
<item>
{$kk}
</item>
```

output:

```
<item>
<prod num="557">
<price currency="USD">29.99</price>
<discount type="CLR">10.00</discount>
</prod>
</item>
```

please guide me, thanks

Comment: Why does the second file have one `item`, the first one, that already has `prod` information? In your expected output you just seem to have copied that particular `item` element. What is supposed to happen with the other elements?

Comment: You can use the function [`functx:copy-attributes`](http://www.xqueryfunctions.com/xq/functx_copy-attributes.html). Be aware that you have to copy the code of the function - it's no internal function of the namespace `functx`,

Comment: @Ansari - It is hard to follow the logic here. If you want to copy "the item attribute", you then need to have such an item.  And I don't see how you would like to select such an item.  Once you have it, we can show you how to copy its attributes.

Answer (score 2):

Try something like below:

```
declare namespace output = "http://www.w3.org/2010/xslt-xquery-serialization";

declare option output:indent 'yes';

let $prices := fn:doc('Price.xml')/prices
let $order := fn:doc('Order.xml')/order where $prices/priceList/prod[@num=$order/item/@num]
return
for $kk in $prices/priceList/prod[@num=$order/item/@num]

return 
<item>{
    $order/item[@num=$kk/@num][1]/@*,
    $kk
}</item>
```

Link: https://xqueryfiddle.liberty-development.net/bdxZ8L